# How to postpone service update until x service finishes docker swarm

Tags: linux, docker, devops, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm stack and one of the services has an hourly cronjob which takes 4 to 5 minutes when I update the service the cronjob process may be running and the service-update will destroy the old image and cause the failure of the scheduled procedure.

If somehow I could postpone the service-update until the scheduled procedure finishes issue is fixed, or maybe there are other workarounds.

NOTES:

- For docker-swarm management and update I use [portainer](https://docs.portainer.io/).
- The hourly task is downloading and processing and inserting some data into the DB.
- We use CI/CD when a code is pushed to GitHub a new image will be created and tested and the portainer will take the new image and update the stack accordingly.